# create an headbar with about dialog in GTK+3

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to create a head bar that should contain an "About" labelled button to show up a dialog when clicked.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate_about(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *about_button;
    GtkWidget *headbar;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);

    headbar = gtk_header_bar_new();
    gtk_header_bar_set_title (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), "Welcome to GTK");
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), TRUE);    

    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 12);
    about_button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_About");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), headbar);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(headbar), about_button);

    g_signal_connect(about_button, "clicked", 
    G_CALLBACK(activate_about), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

static void activate_about(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {

    const gchar *authors[] = {"ad Chi", NULL};

    gtk_show_about_dialog(GTK_WINDOW(window),
                    "program-name", "jjkjk",
                    "version", "0.0.1",
                    "copyright", "(C) 2017 ad Chi",
                    "license-type", GTK_LICENSE_GPL_3_0,
                    "website", "https://github.com/kjk",
                    "comments", "Totally kj",
                    "authors", authors,
                    "documenters", NULL,
                    "logo-icon-name", "start-here",
                    "title", "About kj kj",
                    NULL);

    return;
}
```

The first issue is that now I end up with two bars the window one and that of the headbar widget. I need just one. The second problem is, when I click the button I get

`(button:1727): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 17:59:47.965: invalid cast from 'GtkButton' to 'GtkWindow'`

`(button:1727): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:59:47.982: gtk_window_set_transient_for: assertion 'parent == NULL || GTK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed`. I am new to GTK. I suppose that `gtk_show_about_dialog(GTK_WINDOW(window)...` is not the proper widget to use.

Comment: This is not how [GtkHeaderBar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxdfsxh7eXQ&list=PLN_MPJUQgPVoWz_aHqkFS-0NEW6muJM6B) works. And you should also check [GtkDialog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83KvC_o44Ik&list=PLN_MPJUQgPVo5D2Nc00qN-5r_P1cU_wFE) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate_about(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer window);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *about_button;
    GtkWidget *headbar;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);

    headbar = gtk_header_bar_new();
    gtk_header_bar_set_title (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), "Welcome to GTK");
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), TRUE);    

    vbox = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 12);
    about_button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("_About");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);
    gtk_window_set_titlebar(GTK_WINDOW(window), headbar);
    gtk_header_bar_pack_start(GTK_HEADER_BAR(headbar), about_button);

    g_signal_connect(about_button, "clicked", 
    G_CALLBACK(activate_about), window);

    g_signal_connect_swapped (window, "destroy",
    G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}


static void activate_about(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer window) {

    const gchar *authors[] = {"ad Chi", NULL};

    gtk_show_about_dialog(GTK_WINDOW(window),
                    "program-name", "jjkjk",
                    "version", "0.0.1",
                    "copyright", "(C) 2017 ad Chi",
                    "license-type", GTK_LICENSE_GPL_3_0,
                    "website", "https://github.com/kjk",
                    "comments", "Totally kj",
                    "authors", authors,
                    "documenters", NULL,
                    "logo-icon-name", "start-here",
                    "title", "About kj kj",
                    NULL);

    return;
}
```